# On solution for the simple equation $e^{-x}=x$

Tags: calculus, analysis

I am wondering if it is possible to work out the solution for the equation $\large{e^{-x}=x}$ directly.

The obvious way to get the answer is to plot the two figures and find the intersection, but is it possible to get the solution analytically without the help of plotting? Do you have any ideas on this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

[image]

Comment: I think the curve you've labeled as $y = e^x$ is actually $y = e^{-x}$

Comment: I guess you mean $e^{-x}$?

Comment: It is easy to find the real solutions to $x=\exp(x)$ by noting that $x < \exp(x)$.

Comment: You can approximate the answer using Euler's or Newton's methods.

Comment: @zz20s hi, zz20s, can you elaborate your thought on using Euler's or Newton's methods? thx

Comment: Newton's method : Let $x_{n+1}=x_n-f(x_n)/f'(x_n).$   In this case$ f(x)=x-e^{-x}$  and $ f'(x)=1+e^{-x}.$  Try $x_1=0.6$,

Comment: @user254665 :Ok, now I know, thanks;)

Comment: @MPW . now it is modified, thanks:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$e^x=x$ has no real root.

The root of $e^{-x}=x$ or $xe^x=1$ is $x=W(1)\simeq 0.567143$

$W(X)$ is the Lambert W function, which express the root(s) of $We^{W}=X$ where $W$ is the unknown. The function $W(X)$ is multivaluated in $-e^{-1}<X<0$ , as it appears on the figure below :

[image]

From p.15 in : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function

Example :

$$e^{-x}x^a=b$$
$$e^{-\frac{x}{a}}x=b^{\frac{1}{a}}$$
$$xe^{-\frac{x}{a}}=b^{\frac{1}{a}}$$
$$(-\frac{x}{a})e^{-\frac{x}{a}} =(-\frac{1}{a})b^{\frac{1}{a}}$$
With $y=-\frac{x}{a}$ and $X=-\frac{b^{\frac{1}{a}}}{a}$
$$ye^y =X $$
$$y=W(X)$$
$$-\frac{x}{a}=W\left(-\frac{b^{\frac{1}{a}}}{a}\right)$$
$$x=-aW\left(-\frac{b^{\frac{1}{a}}}{a}\right)$$

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for the information, a further question is whether there is an extension of the Lambert W function which can solve the equations like $e^{x}=x^{\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ is real.

Comment: The analytic solution of $e^x=x^a$ is : $$x=-aW(-\frac{1}{a})$$

Comment: I guess the general solution for the equation $e^{-x}x^{a} = b$ will be: $x=-a \cdot W(-\frac{b}{a})$?   Checked with Matlab, seems it is not a correct answer for $a = 2, b = 3$ (the left side gives 9, not 3).

Comment: Not exactly, it should be : $x=-aW\left(-\frac{b^{1/a}}{a} \right)$

Comment: Yes, I just used Matlab simulation to figure out the solution. I will try to derive it myself today, and if I does not make it, I can ask you how to do it again :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: hi, JJacquelin . On the question of $e^{-x}x^{a}=b$, we can rewrite it as $e^{-y} \cdot y = \frac{\sqrt[a]{b}}{a}$ with $y = \frac{x}{a}$. But how can we derive the next step to prove that the solution of $e^{-y} \cdot y = \frac{\sqrt[a]{b}}{a}$ is $y = -W(-\frac{\sqrt[a]{b}}{a})$. As the definition of Lambert W function is not that clear for me (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: See the example added to my first answer.

Comment: I see, Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

The solution cannot be expressed with elementary functions.

It can be rewritten as $-1 = (-x)e^{(-x)}$, and the solution of this equation is given/defined by the Lambert W function :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: You should make more clear that that is just a change of notation more than anything...

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD : do you say that $\ln(a)$ is also a change of notation for the solution of $e^x=a$? If not, why? And what is different? (ok, I play a little the devil advocate here )

Comment: So $-x = W(-1)$?

Comment: @Tryss . Hi, Tryss, thanks a lot for the information, a further question is whether there is an extension of the Lambert W function which can solve the equations like $e^{x}=x^{\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ is real. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The Newton iteration for the equation $e^{-x}=x$, rewritten in the form $e^{-x}-x=0$, is

$$x_{k+1}=x_k-\frac{e^{-x_k}-x_k}{-e^{-x_k}-1}.$$

Simplify a bit for convenience:

$$x_{k+1}=x_k+\frac{e^{-x_k}-x_k}{e^{-x_k}+1}=\frac{e^{-x_k}-x_k+x_ke^{-x_k}+x_k}{e^{-x_k}+1}=\frac{e^{-x_k}+x_k e^{-x_k}}{e^{-x_k}+1} = \frac{x_k+1}{e^{x_k}+1}.$$

Using the graph we make the naive guess $x_0=0$. Then $x_1=\frac{1}{2}$, $x_2=\frac{3}{2e^{1/2}+2} \approx 0.5663$. The error is already less than $10^{-3}$. The number of correct digits roughly doubles at each subsequent step from this point on, so you get floating point accuracy in three or four more steps.